# How to loop through different cut values for a step function in R with caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I apologize if this is a beginner question, but I'm working on the exercises from the book An Introduction to Statistical Learning for R and can't work out a solution for the following problem:

The task is to compare the accuracy of regression models using step functions with different values of cuts and using cross-validation. I chose to do it using the `caret` package.

```
library(ISLR)   
library(caret) 
Wage <- Wage
```

Just loading the required packages and loading the dataset I've been working with (included in the `ISLR` package)

```
cv.errors <- rep(0, 13) 
stepfit <- train(wage ~ cut(age, 7), 
 data = Wage,
 method = "lm",
  trControl = trainControl(
   method = "cv",
   number = 10))
cv.errors[1] <- stepfit$results$RMSE
```

So far so good, the code works and lets me save the resulting RMSE value of the model using 7 cuts in the prepared vector.

```
set.seed(1)
for(i in 2:14) {
 stepfit <- train(
  wage ~ cut(age, i), data = Wage,
  method = "lm",
   trControl = trainControl(
    method = "cv",
    number = 10
  ))
cv.errors[i] <- stepfit$results$RMSE
}
```

Trying to loop over the cut values from 2 to 14 however doesn't work and gives me the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) :
 undefined columns selected
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the input is a formula, it cannot read off the variable, so for example:

```
set.seed(1)
for(i in 2:14) {
 f = as.formula(paste0("wage ~ cut(age, ",i,")"))
 stepfit <- train(form = f, 
  data = Wage,
  method = "lm",
   trControl = trainControl(
    method = "cv",
    number = 10
  ))
cv.errors[i] <- stepfit$results$RMSE
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! It makes sense and solves the problem.